# Javascript unexpected Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For some odd reason this line of code is being identified as an

This specific line is

```
  `Unexpected identifier` 

    bmr =  66 + ( 6.23 * weightInlbs ) + ( 12.7 heightInInches ) - ( 6.8 * age );
```

this is the whole code

```
function metricComputation() {
    var age = document.getElementById("age");
    var weightInlbs = document.getElementById("weight");
    var heightInInches =  feetToInches(new Number(document.getElementById("heightinFt")) , document.getElementById("heightinIn"));
    var bmr;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender");


    if(gender === "male"){
         bmr =  66 + ( 6.23 * weightInlbs ) + ( 12.7 heightInInches ) - ( 6.8 * age );
    }

}
```

And this is the whole markup

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bmrcalc.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <center>
                    <h1>Basal Metabolic Rate</h1>
                Height: <input type = "text" id ="heightinFt"> ft  <input type = "text" id = "heightinIn"> in <br>
                Weight: <input type = "text" id ="weight">lbs<br>
                Age: <input type = "text" id = "age"><br>
                Gender:<select id = "gender">
                    <option value = "male">Male</option>
                    <option value = "female">Female</option>
                <select> <br>
                <button onclick = "metricComputation()">Compute</button>
                <div id = "result"></div>
            </center>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check on which column of your code the exception appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to multiply?

```
bmr =  66 + ( 6.23 * weightInlbs ) + ( 12.7 * heightInInches ) - ( 6.8 * age );
// -----------------------------------------/\
```

Comment: blah, didn't see the error. I will not code again in a netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug:

```
12.7 heightInInches
```

the identifier `heightInInches` is not expected to be in this location. What is expected is an operator like *, +, - or /

Answer (score 0):

```
if(gender === "male"){
     bmr =  66 + ( 6.23 * weightInlbs ) + ( 12.7 * heightInInches ) - ( 6.8 * age );
}
```

You forgot the ***** in `( 12.7  heightInInches )`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "*" between "12.7" and  heightInInches":

```
bmr =  66 + ( 6.23 * weightInlbs ) + ( 12.7 * heightInInches ) - ( 6.8 * age );
```